# Postfix (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)

Tags: postfix

I've an issue with postfix in sending outbound emails, the emails remain in the active queu with this message when I use mailq (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)

the below is the configuration of main.cf

```
  GNU nano 4.8                        main.cf                                   
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_un>
myhostname = example.com
#myhostname = ip-address.eu-west-3.compute.internal
mydomain = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = example.com, $myhostname, ip-address.eu-west-3.compute.>
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

Comment: That means you haven't provisioned IPv6 to your EC2 instance. It is probably not the cause of the problem. Look for other log entries.

Comment: If you aren't able to send any email, even on IPv4, make sure you have [requested the removal of the port 25 block in AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/).

Comment: I want to add that I got tcpdump logs and all telnet SMTP domain on port 25 it gives me flag s with no response from the destination from google or any other email server.